# How to make twig render a form element with a different theme block from propel form types

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, propel

I was trying to use the block_name attribute to select a different theme for a certain form input:

```
$builder->add('titleFragments', new Form\DerivedType\SortableCollectionType(), array( 
        'label' => ' ',
        'type' => new TitlefragmentType(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'block_name' => 'anotherThemeBlock',
));
```

But it didn't work as expected and I couldn't find any documentation regarding the block_name parameter. So my question is less what this parameter is good for than how to define another block theme for a certain form input.

Comment: You can create a new block, and if you name it properly, it'll only be used on that given field of that given form. Check the [form block naming conventions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-fragment-naming) in the Sf docs to see how.